# Exportar BD con mysqldump (the system cannot find the file specified)

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb, mysqldump

Estoy tratando de exportar una base de datos local (Xampp) mediante mysqldump.

> Cuando se exporte, se espera que tenga el nombre de: **dbBackup_Fecha.sql**

`mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p dbName > dbBackup_%Date:~6,4%%Date:~3,2%%Date:~0,2%.sql`

La estoy ejecutando desde Xampp Shell y me aparece el siguiente error:
***the system cannot find the file specified***

Cabe mencionar que ya tengo agregadas las variables de entorno de **C:\xampp\mysql/bin** corectamente

Comment: Una pregunta esa ruta no esta mal ``C:\xampp\mysql/bin`` no debería ser ``C:\xampp\mysql\bin`` si eso puedes intentar poner ``mysql -h localhost -u root -p [database name] < C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqlDump.sql`` con tu ruta por si acaso, para asegurarte de que no estas cometiendo errores al escribir la ruta puedes usar la tecla ``tab`` o mejor dicho tabulador para que se auto complete la ruta, poco a poco. Espero haberte sido de ayuda :-)