# Exportar DB con fecha actual - mysqldump

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysqldump

Estoy tratando de exportar una base de datos local (Xampp) mediante mysqldump.

> Cuando se exporte, se espera que tenga el nombre de: **dbBackup_Fecha.sql**

`mysqldump -h localhost -u root -p dbName > dbBackup_%Date:~6,4%%Date:~3,2%%Date:~0,2%.sql`

La estoy ejecutando desde Xampp Shell y me aparece el siguiente error:
***the system cannot find the file specified***

Cabe mencionar que ya tengo agregadas las variables de entorno de **C:\xampp\mysql\bin** corectamente. Cualquier aportación se agradece

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Exportar BD con mysqldump (the system cannot find the file specified)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/537047/exportar-bd-con-mysqldump-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)

Comment: No dupliques preguntas, contesta las aclaraciones que te piden en los comentarios, y para editar el contenido de la pregunta pulsa sobre el enlace Editar que aparece en el pie de la pregunta y no la repitas con la corrección, gracias